# Non-polar molecules are soluble in non-polar solvents (hexane) but not in water, Why?

Tags: water, solubility, intermolecular-forces

My book says that non-polar simple molecular substances can dissove when added to a non-polar solvent, such as hexane due to intermolecular forces forming between the molecules and the solvent.

However, it says simply that 
**non-polar molecules do not interact with the dipoles in water, hence simple molecular substances tend be me insoluble in polar solvents**

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Well, it is as simple as that: no dipoles, hence no dipole-dipole interactions with water, so water is better off interacting with itself and leaving your substance alone.

Comment: You mean no permanent dipole-dipole interactions? @IvanNeretin

Comment: Yeah, of course. You can still have induced dipoles, but those are weak.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Got it! I answered my own question! Uprate if it may be useful to other people and thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

For a molecule to be soluble in water, **permanent dipole-dipole interactions** are required.

Non-polar molecules only have induced dipole-dipole interactions, which are not sufficient for the molecule to dissolve in water.

*"The water molecules are better off interacting with themselves"*

Credits @IvanNeretin